# How to fix JSON invalid control character errors?

Tags: python, json

FWIW, I have used other JSON APIs without issue (Tumblr, Twitter, etc.).

My Google Blogger Client uses Google's Blogger API so I can do things such as download blog posts from a user, or download a user's images.

Here are the important parts of my Blogger Client:

```
    import requests
    #import json
    #import demjson

class BloggerClient(object):
    """ Client interface for Blogger API. """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3'

    def _send_request(self, url, parameters={}):
        """ Sends an HTTP GET request to Blogger API.
            Returns JSON decoded response. """

        # Format the full URL
        url = '{base}{url}?'.format(base=self.base, url=url)

        # API key is always required, so add it to parameters
        parameters['key'] = self.key

        try:
            # Requests module formats parameters into the URL for me
            r = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
            print 'Connecting:', r.url, '\n'            # debug
        except:
            print "** Could not reach url:\n", url
            return
        return r.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

If I run the script 5 times, with the same valid input, it will fail a random amount of times.

Here is the error I just got (even though it succeeded when I ran it 1 minute ago on the same input):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\programming\python\corerip\blogger_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    posts = b.get_all_posts()
  File "G:\programming\python\corerip\site_blogger.py", line 25, in get_all_pos
s
    page_of_posts = self.client.get_posts(blog_id)
  File "G:\programming\python\corerip\client_blogger.py", line 64, in get_posts
    return self._send_request(api_url, kwargs)
  File "G:\programming\python\corerip\client_blogger.py", line 30, in _send_req
est
    return r.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.3.0-py2.7.egg\requests\models.
y", line 763, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 101 column 3095 (char 38567)
```

**It should have responded with this JSON:**

http://pastebin.com/5iW1C8Dc

**The input URL was:**

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/233501935878754401/posts
?key=[YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY_HERE]

If I run the script again it will probably succeed. It doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe it has something to do with JSON modules not handling unicode properly by default?

Can someone please help me solve this random error? The fact that it appears to be random just boggles my mind.

I have tried almost every json module, they all fail randomly when using Google's APIs.

edit:
I have tried to 'escape' the characters by using a raw string, but that also fails:

```
    api_response = r'''{rtext}'''.format(rtext=r.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 274
75: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What *does* the API respond with when it fails? Instead of directly doing `return r.json()`, assign `content = r.content` and decode it explicitely with `data = json.loads(content)`, and wrap that line in a `try..except` block. In the `except:` (when the JSON decoding failed), do a `print repr(content)`.

Comment: *Aside*: You may want to check the status code: `if r.ok: return r.json`. But this doesn't related to the problem you are reporting.

Comment: FWIW, I ran `for i in range(100): requests.get( 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/233501935878754401/posts?key=VALID_KEY_HERE').json()` and got no exceptions.

Comment: @LukasGraf Here is what the API responds with: http://pastebin.com/g0NCp3YQ   (The whole response does not fit inside my cmd window)